# gridview dropdownlist value issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a drop down list inside the gridview as shown below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines=">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                 <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblService" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="RowArea">RowArea</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="ColumnArea">ColumnArea</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="DataArea">DataArea</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="FilterArea">FilterArea</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

and i have a button outside the gridview. When i click on the button i want to retrieve the values inside gridview that is in label and dropdownlist

```
 foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                Label lbl = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblService");
                String field = lbl.Text;
                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DropDownList1");
                String areatype = ddl1.SelectedItem.Value;
                String value = ddl1.SelectedValue;
                String result = field + "," + areatype;
                objList.Add(result);


            }
```

but when i execute the above code on button click i get the label value but dropdownlist value always shows the default value and not the selected value.

Comment: Try using `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to get currently selected value, and pass this value to `RowDataBound` event if necessary.

Comment: how could you tell me in detail

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried select index change but select index change doesnt get fired i have put autopostback = true  and enableviewstate=true

Comment: This is solved thanks. I had not put ispostback